# Swift - override present and dismiss in UIViewController (modal) in order to run some command every time a view controller is presented or dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a floating button that always stays on top. I can't really control much about this button,  except show/hide. Whenever a ViewController is **presented as a modal**, I want to hide this floating button if it's not already hidden, and when the ViewController is dismissed, I want to show it again. I can control this state with an import and something very simple like `Library.show()` and `Library.hide()`. I want to do this only in one place in the code to make sure that it works everywhere now and in the future. Any ideas on how to do this? Any perf or memory considerations?

Comment: You may want to subclass UIViewController and then override functions like `viewDidDisappear` (or similar). Then, make every other view controller in your app inherit from your custom one. Always remember to call `super.viewDidDisappear` (or similar) to ensure your original functions are hit.

Comment: I thought about doing this but that will require a code change in every single view controller and all future view controllers being presented modally will need to make sure they inherit from the custom class. This method seems a bit error prone to me :/

Comment: I can relate to that. Maybe try an extension on `UIViewController`, and then use an `NSKeyValueObservation` on some property of `UIViewController`? I don't know enough to provide an answer but this may be a good direction.